# Change the App icon in Liferay?

Tags: icons, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I want to change this Icon of my Portlet:
[image: image: how to change the icon in control panel]

I searched in [Liferay Documentation](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-1/what-is-liferay) and [Forums](http://www.liferay.com/it/community/forums) but I have not found the answer.

Comment: I'm not into liferay so I'm not sure if I interpretated your question correctly, but maybe this helps you: https://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+to+change+the+favorites+icon

Comment: @bish Thanks but this is not favicon. I want to change the app icon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to do it for your custom-app then here is what you need to do:

1. Change the `icon.png` file in `/docroot/icon.png` in your portlet's source.
2. the path is configured in your `liferay-portlet.xml` as:

   ```
   <liferay-portlet-app>
       <portlet>
           <portlet-name>mycustom</portlet-name>
           <icon>/icon.png</icon> <--- See this
           ....
       </portlet>
   </liferay-portlet-app>
   ```
3. build and deploy your portlet.
4. Clear browser cache before checking.

This should also affect the image when you add the portlet on a page with borders.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @PrakashK I tried but it doesn't work. I see that small icon only on portlet border.